# express session is not persistent when server deployed to heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I built a simple user authentication app with `React, node and Passport JS`. When on `localhost`, it successfully stores the session and persist the user but after deploying on heroku it doesn't persist the session.

I checked networks tab and found that sameSite attribute is by default set to `lax`
and if client wants to get cross site cookies it should be set to `none` and must have `secure` attribute set. **But when I set sameSite to none and secure to true, client don't get the cookie from the server (e.g set-cookie header is not present in response)[image]**.

I don't know where am I doing wrong.

***This is my Server JS***

```js
// Middlewares
app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://authclient.netlify.app",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
    },
    store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: dbURI }),
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser("secret"));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
require("./passportConfig")(passport);
//______________________________________

//Routes
app.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) res.send(info.message);
    else {
      req.logIn(user, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send("Logged In!");
      });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```